# Javascript library to generate workflow configuration diagrams

Tags: javascript, workflow, diagram

I have a set of predefined flow diagrams, and I need a way to display the diagram and allow the user to interactively set inputs and/or properties at various nodes in the diagram.  The nodes/connections of the diagram are fixed and cannot be edited by the user.

I know there are several options for diagram editors, but those would need heavy modification for what I need.  Any suggestions for javascript libraries/apps that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell us what technology you are using for the diagrams if any.

It sounds like you need two things. Firstly a method of displaying a directed graph (which is what a flowchart is) in a browser. Secondly, a tool to add interaction to the graph.

Here is a rough list of some of the graphics toolkits that are relevant:

- JsPlumb
- JavaScript InfoViz Toolkit
- http://processingjs.org/
- http://raphaeljs.com/
- https://github.com/mbostock/d3
- [NodeViz](https://code.google.com/p/nodeviz/) might also be usable. It adds a PHP back-end onto some javascript front-end tools.

All of these will require a lot of programming though. I'm not aware of anything "out-of-the-box" that will do what you want - I've certainly been looking for similar tools for a while though what I really want is a data-driven interactive graph tool (not to be confused with charting tools of which there are many).

Update: I've just come across http://www.jointjs.com/ as well. This is built over Raphael and seems promising.